# Matching y axis points together

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I have successfully read in data from a catalog, and I have graphed what I need. However, I need one more thing. I would like to correspond the different "standard_deviation" values with the "number" via "half-light radius." In the graph shown, the "number" is not an axis on the graph, however, there will in this case be ten "number 9's" for example. I would like a way to match the points of these same-numbered points with some sort of line, as I showed in the image below (I just drew lines randomly to give you an idea of what I want).

In this example, assume that every point one one of the drawn lines is of the same "number." A point of a "number" will have ten different "standard_deviation" values, 1 through 10, and ten different "half_light radius" values, which are the values I would like to match. I've pasted my read/plot code below. How would I do this?

```
newvid = asciitable.read('user4.cat') 

n_new = newvid['n']
re_new = newvid['re']
number = newvid['number']
standard_deviation = newvid['standard_deviation']

plt.title('sersic parameter vs. standard deviation distribution of noise') 
plt.xlabel('standard deviation')
plt.ylabel('sersic parameter')
plt.xlim(0,12)
plt.ylim(0,5) 
plt.scatter(standard_deviation, n_new)
plt.show()

plt.title('half-light radius vs. standard deviation distribution of noise') 
plt.xlabel('standard deviation')
plt.ylabel('half-light radius')
plt.xlim(0,12)
plt.ylim(-2,15)
plt.scatter(standard_deviation,re_new)
plt.show()
```

[image: Example Graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what I think you want, you'll have to use the `plot` function instead of `scatter` in order to connect the lines.  Depending on how your data is arranged, you may have to split or sort your data, so that you can plot all points of each number at once, sorted by standard deviation.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

newvid = asciitable.read('user4.cat') 

n_new = newvid['n']
re_new = newvid['re']
number = newvid['number']
std_dev = newvid['standard_deviation']

n_max = float(number.max())  # for coloring later

plt.figure()
plt.title('sersic parameter vs. standard deviation distribution of noise') 
plt.xlabel('standard deviation')
plt.ylabel('sersic parameter')
plt.xlim(0,12)
plt.ylim(0,5) 
for n in np.unique(number):
    n_mask = number == n                 # pick out just where n_new is the current n
    order = np.argsort(std_dev[n_mask])  # sort by std_dev, so line doesn't zig zag
    plt.plot(std_dev[n_mask][order], n_new[n_mask][order],
             label=str(n), color=cm.jet(n/n_max))    # label and color by n
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.figure()
plt.title('half-light radius vs. standard deviation distribution of noise') 
plt.xlabel('standard deviation')
plt.ylabel('half-light radius')
plt.xlim(0,12)
plt.ylim(-2,15)

# do one plot per number
for n in np.unique(number):
    n_mask = number == n                 # pick out just where n_new is the current n
    order = np.argsort(std_dev[n_mask])  # sort by std_dev, so line doesn't zig zag
    plt.plot(std_dev[n_mask][order], re_new[n_mask][order],
             label=str(n), color=cm.jet(n/n_max))    # label and color by n
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

With random data:
[image: lines]

To do a colorbar instead of a legend:

```
m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.jet)
m.set_array(number)
plt.colorbar(m)
```

[image: colorbar]

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! Do you know how to embolden one random "line" in the plot?

Comment: Yeah, with the linewidth option: use `lw=2` or `lw=3` in the `plot` command.  Do you really mean random, or one particular one?  If you want, say `n=3` particular, something like `lw=3 if n==3 else 1`.  If you really want to do one randomly, just pick that `n` randomly in advance: `nbold = np.random.choice(number)`, then `lw=3 if n==nbold else 1`

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! One more quick question: I have 42 things in my key. Is there any way to make the key readable, because at the moment, the screen itself cuts off the key at 28 or so.

Comment: @vdogsandman You can change the font size and spacing in the legend options, see the docs for `plt.legend()`

Comment: @vdogsandman, Probably using a legend isn't the best solution for you.  A `colorbar` would work but is a bit tricky to implement if you're not already using an image plot.

Comment: @vdogsandman See my edit for how to do a colorbar instead of a legend.